# Does it make sense to test my model with another model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, classification, modeling

I've built a binary logistic model using R's `glm()` method. I already know the data aren't extremely predictive but I think my model can do a couple points better than random. One way I thought of testing the predictive power of the model's returned probabilities was to build a second, "meta" model using the holdout set, using the first model's probabilities as the independent variable. It looks like this:

```
test_x$Probs <- predict(model, newdata = test_x,type="response")
meta_model <- lm(test_y ~ Probs, data = test_x)

> meta_model

Call:
lm(formula = test_y ~ Prob, data = test_x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         Prob  
     0.0686       0.6966
```

Is this a sensible thing to do? This seems like a good result but I can't tell if this is an independent test. I know it's not eh most rigorous validation, but is it a valid measure?

Answer (score 1):

GLM are not so easy to validate as there is no straight-forward way of knowing what proportion of your data's variability is being explained.

You could use  the [Likelihood-ratio test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/129958/glm-in-r-which-pvalue-represents-the-goodness-of-fit-of-entire-model) which to see whether your model identifies with the null model (basically that's like knowing whether or not the adj. R-sq. is “too low”), and then you also have the [Deviance goodness of fit test](http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/04/26/deviance-goodness-of-fit-test-for-poisson-regression/) which lets you see whether your model identifies with the saturated model (the equivalent of knowing whether or not the adj. R-sq. value would be “high enough”).

PS: Check out [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58679/goodness-of-fit-in-a-glm-with-scaled-deviance?rq=1) too.

Answer (score 0):

Look up "[forecast encompassing test](https://www.economicsnetwork.ac.uk/showcase/cook_encompassing)" in interweb. It relates to comparing two model's forecasts. Basically you try to see whether one model has information in the residuals of another, i.e. encompassing it.

Comment: Isn't this adapted to time series analysis?